# Confusion Regarding Custom Font Face

Tags: html, css, cpanel, web-development-server

I made a website that uses the Avenir font-face. It appears that the font does not work for windows machine (I developed this website on my Mac).

My issue is that, based on [this](https://www.pagecloud.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-any-website) tutorial I expected the font to load correctly. Up to this moment the Avenir font appears fine on my Mac but I have a separate contact who tells me that the font loaded for his machine (apparently a windows machine) is the default Times New Roman font.

I am using CPanel, if that matters and here is how the project is structured:

I have a `style.css` file that has the `@font-face` set, and the font family set globally per the linked tutorial.

[image]
[image]

On CPanel, I have the `style.css` and the `.woff` files uploaded in the same root directory, under the File Manager > public_html. My project structure looks like this:

[image]

Does this mean that my CSS file is unable to find the .woff file? Or would this be an issue with CPanel?

It is hard to debug because I apparently have Avenir on my computer already. Therefore, the font shows up just fine without the `@font-face` and all of the `.woff` files. Except for the font, all of the colors and spacing is rendering correctly from the `style.css` file; only the font is not displaying correctly.

Stack Exchange recommended [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908905/font-face-not-working-on-windows-version-of-browsers) post to me but in that post the issue appeared to be a relative path issue. I doubt the source of my issue is the same since the `.woff` files are in the same directory, and I have tried the import statement in two different ways (`src: url('font')` and `src: url('./font')`).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you check the console errors in developer tools ? if your fonts fails to load you will get 404 error.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My console is clear but I have asked my contact what his browser console looks like on his windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't find any issue in the font face definition. You could possibly use `local` and `url` both in the `src` property.

Try giving the full url of the font file in `url` parameter in `src`.

Also consider reading the below question :

What are Google Webfonts or Typekit alternatives to Avenir Next Pro?
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16036/what-are-google-webfonts-or-typekit-alternatives-to-avenir-next-pro

I used the css from here : https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito&display=swap for the below demo.

Hope this helps.

```css
h1 {
font-size: 50px;
font-family: 'Nunito';
}

/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Nunito Regular'), local('Nunito-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/nunito/v12/XRXV3I6Li01BKofIOOaBTMnFcQIG.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Nunito Regular'), local('Nunito-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/nunito/v12/XRXV3I6Li01BKofIMeaBTMnFcQIG.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Nunito Regular'), local('Nunito-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/nunito/v12/XRXV3I6Li01BKofIOuaBTMnFcQIG.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Nunito Regular'), local('Nunito-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/nunito/v12/XRXV3I6Li01BKofIO-aBTMnFcQIG.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Nunito Regular'), local('Nunito-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/nunito/v12/XRXV3I6Li01BKofINeaBTMnFcQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is Nunito Font</h1>
```

Comment: Given that there were no issues with the font face definition, my client recommended that I simply use a different font, just as you suggested. My client says that Avenir is not considered, "web safe", though it is not clear to me why it would not work if I uploaded the custom files onto the directory. 

Thank you for the recommendation for Nunito font! I will definitely take a look and propose it to my partner.

Comment: @im2wddrf : I'm glad it helped :) Cheers.